# Kendo UI Angular: Is there a way to select multiple dates in the Kendo Calendar Angular Component?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-angular-ui

Looking at [this Kendo Calendar dojo example](https://dojo.telerik.com/) ([docs](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/calendar/selection)) we can select multiple dates by using the below configuration.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // create Calendar from div HTML element
  $("#calendar").kendoCalendar({
        selectable: "multiple",
        weekNumber: true,
        disableDates: ["we", "sa"]
    });
});
```

I want to use the same functions with the Angular Component described [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dateinputs/api/CalendarComponent/#toc-weeknumber), but I can't find the configuration for this in de docs. Am I overlooking something or is this not possible? If it is not possible, my question is why not?

PS: I am using this Angular Component in an ionic 2 app.